# Upgraded to ruby 1.9.2 and getting Segmentation Fault errors in nokogiri

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-snow-leopard, segmentation-fault, nokogiri

I decided to upgrade to 1.9.2 ruby yesterday and also installed rvm to do it. I ran a few recent files I had working previously on 1.8.7 but anything requiring nokogiri fails with the following errors.

```
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/nokogiri-1.4.3.1/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]
```

I am running nokogiri 1.4.3.1, ruby 1.9.2 on OSX Snow Leopard 10.6.4

Answer (score 5):

If you get a Segmentation fault error from nokogiri, e.g., when you open your rails console, and you are using RVM and your ruby version is 1.9.2 something (mine currently is 1.9.2p136) and you notice a reference to ruby 1.8.7 just after the nokogiri segmentation fault message, then perhaps the following may be of assistance...

ERROR

```
$ rails c
/Users/lex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@lmi/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]

Abort trap
```

SOLUTION

(1) make sure that ruby 1.8.7 is not a rvm ruby version:
-  run `rvm list`

> if it is, then remove it:  ex:  `rvm uninstall ree-1.8.7-2010.02`

(2) uninstall nokogiri and libxml2 related dependencies:

```
$ gem uninstall nokogiri
$ brew uninstall libxml2
```

(3) install libxml2 using homebrew

```
$ brew install libxml2
$ brew link libxml2
```

(4) install libxslt from source

```
$ wget ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxslt-1.1.26.tar.gz
$ tar -zxvf libxslt-1.1.26.tar.gz
$ cd libxslt-1.1.26
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.26    --with-libxml-prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.7
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

(5) install nokogiri

```
gem install nokogiri
```

Alternative (ensure your paths are correct): `gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.7/include --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.7/lib --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.26`

(6) test

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.3)
>>
```

Getting and keeping your Ruby XML parsing libraries running properly can be an issue.  Here are some alternatives:  LibXML, Hpricot, REXML

Comment: thanks, this solved some sporadic segfault issues that I was having. I do get "WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.7.3, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.7" now though.

Comment: libxslt from brew seems to work well and does compile from source. I'd recommend editing step 4 to just brew install libxslt

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you just need to tell `rvm` to use the correct ruby.

```
rvm 1.9.2
```

Otherwise why would your second line indicate 1.8.7?

You shouldn't expect native code compiled against one major version of ruby to link cleanly to another. There's no ABI contract, afaik.

- https://rvm.io/rvm/basics/
- https://rvm.io/rvm/cli/

Comment: Thanks but had done all that previously. I had set rvm to default to 1.9.2 in terminal and tested that was set and it was. I have no idea why 1.8.7 is mentioned either.

Comment: There's not enough context in your question to give a meaningful answer. What command were you running? Did it crash immediately? How did you get the backtrace (what little of it we can see)?

Comment: Thx and sorry for the lack of info. I was running a ruby script from BBEdit to the Terminal. It fails straight away as soon as it gets to the require 'nokogiri' line. What you see in my question is everything in the terminal screen relating to the error.

Comment: You can't expect processes like BBEdit to pick up rvm's ruby. rvm is Terminal-specific in the sense that it sets up your environment variables when you open a login shell. You'll need to tell BBEdit where to find rvm's current ruby. I've not used BBEdit for several years but I'm sure its frightening preferences dialog has some way to set $PATH and so on. This might help, http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/textmate/

Comment: BBedit's "Run In Terminal" works fine running a Ruby script as long as the script uses `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`. I just put `puts RUBY_VERSION, %x{which ruby}` into a script and ran it and got back the right path and version info: `/Users/greg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby` and `1.9.2`. If you use the `Run...` menu it will use the system Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible you originally built Nokogiri on Leopard then upgraded to Snow Leopard?

If so, do a `gem uninstall nokogiri` followed by `gem install nokogiri`. That will force it to recompile for your currently selected Ruby and OS.

I saw the similar problems when I upgraded from Leopard to Snow Leopard, and reinstalled my Ruby. The gems didn't get recompiled, so I had to force several of them to do so.

Comment: Thx will try that as you never know but I definitely installed it well after my move to Snow Leopard.

Comment: You might also confirm that your version of [XCode](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/) is current. I've seen comments about the previous rev. causing problems. The current rev is 3.2.4 per Apple's XCode page.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `rvm requirements` in Terminal and see if there are any missing dependencies. (It shows in red in my OS X)

The returned notes helped me install missing dependencies with brew, with clearly stated steps.

Answer (score 0):

all the suggestions here didn't work for me, but the abridged [answer to this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413209/error-cross-thread-violation-on-rb-gc) by mmrobins  below:

```
rvm gemset empty
```

followed by a standard bundle install got everything working for me.