# Install a gem for just ruby 1.9.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

How do I specify for what version of ruby I would like to install a gem in?

Comment: This is probably related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575981/nokogiri-segmentation-fault

Answer (score 4):

Are you using RVM? If so, just go to you ruby:

```
rvm 1.9.2-head
```

then do

```
gem install whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

use RVM. [This](http://railscasts.com/episodes/200-rails-3-beta-and-rvm) is a good tutorial.

Do focus on creating gemset

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [RVM](http://rvm.io), that way you can manage what gems are installed for what ruby/rails.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not using RVM?

```
$> rvm use 1.9.2 
$> gem install <gem name>
```

The gem will be installed only for Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: I am using rvm but when trying to install nokogiri it seems to think that it is installing for 1.8.7 and I am getting seg fault errors. `/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]

Abort trap` I thought reinstall the gem would work but nothing changed.