# RSpec throws segmentation fault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, segmentation-fault, spree

sometimes my test suite throws a segmentation fault for no reasons. Here is the output:

```
/Users/Test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:268: [BUG] Bus Error
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0209 p:---- s:0839 b:0839 l:000838 d:000838 CFUNC  :-
c:0208 p:0068 s:0835 b:0833 l:000832 d:000832 METHOD /Users/Test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:268
c:0207 p:0031 s:0828 b:0828 l:000827 d:000827 METHOD /Users/Test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:260
c:0206 p:0084 s:0825 b:0825 l:000824 d:000824 METHOD /Users/Test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:196
c:0205 p:0166 s:0818 b:0818 l:000817 d:000817 METHOD /Users/Test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:159
c:0204 p:0050 s:0811 b:0811 l:000810 d:000810 METHOD /Users/Test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:58
c:0203 p:0089 s:0806 b:0806 l:000805 d:000805 METHOD /Users/Test/Dropbox/projects/rails/my_shop/app/models/line_item_decorator.rb:7
c:0202 p:---- s:0802 b:0802 l:000801 d:000801 FINISH
c:0201 p:---- s:0800 b:0800 l:000370 d:000799 IFUNC 
c:0200 p:0008 s:0798 b:0797 l:001cd0 d:000796 BLOCK  /Users/Test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:94
c:0199 p:---- s:0794 b:0794 l:000793 d:000793 FINISH
c:0198 p:---- s:0792 b:0792 l:000791 d:000791 CFUNC  :map
c:0197 p:0028 s:0789 b:0789 l:000788 d:000788 METHOD /Users/Test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb:60
c:0196 p:0030 s:0784 b:0784 l:001cd0 d:001cd0 METHOD /Users/Test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:94
....
```

We are using Spree Commerce with Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.9. Here is the Gemfile.lock:

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/spree/spree.git
  revision: 0d81ee0a2265797641ce90e120ea4fd8b085fc12
  ref: 0d81ee0a2265797641ce90e120ea4fd8b085fc12
  branch: 1-2-stable
  specs:
    spree (1.2.0)
      spree_api (= 1.2.0)
      spree_cmd (= 1.2.0)
      spree_core (= 1.2.0)
      spree_dash (= 1.2.0)
      spree_promo (= 1.2.0)
      spree_sample (= 1.2.0)
    spree_api (1.2.0)
      spree_core (= 1.2.0)
    spree_cmd (1.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14.6)
    spree_core (1.2.0)
      activemerchant (= 1.28.0)
      acts_as_list (= 0.1.4)
      awesome_nested_set (= 2.1.4)
      aws-sdk (~> 1.3.4)
      cancan (= 1.6.7)
      deface (>= 0.9.0)
      ffaker (~> 1.12.0)
      highline (= 1.6.11)
      jquery-rails (~> 2.0)
      kaminari (= 0.13.0)
      money (= 5.0.0)
      paperclip (~> 2.8)
      rabl (= 0.7.2)
      rails (~> 3.2.9)
      ransack (~> 0.7.0)
      select2-rails (~> 3.0)
      state_machine (= 1.1.2)
      stringex (~> 1.3.2)
    spree_dash (1.2.0)
      httparty (~> 0.8.1)
      spree_core (= 1.2.0)
    spree_promo (1.2.0)
      spree_core (= 1.2.0)
    spree_sample (1.2.0)
      spree_core (= 1.2.0)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise
  revision: d06f95d861d19547b407bc2e50b03667e5572ebd
  branch: 1-2-stable
  specs:
    spree_auth_devise (1.2.0)
      cancan (~> 1.6.7)
      devise (~> 2.2.3)
      devise-encryptable (= 0.1.1)
      spree_core

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git
  revision: 5488725cb2587973e7ff809f234eb437a76424f4
  branch: master
  specs:
    sunspot (2.0.0)
      pr_geohash (~> 1.0)
      rsolr (~> 1.0.7)
    sunspot_rails (2.0.0)
      nokogiri
      sunspot (= 2.0.0)
    sunspot_solr (2.0.0)

GIT
  remote: https://github.com/Goltergaul/spree_i18n.git
  revision: 98662fb03d250b920a0d8481fa6448bf56497474
  specs:
    spree_i18n (1.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
      spree (~> 1.1)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.9)
      actionpack (= 3.2.9)
      mail (~> 2.4.4)
    actionpack (3.2.9)
      activemodel (= 3.2.9)
      activesupport (= 3.2.9)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    active_utils (2.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.11)
      i18n
    activemerchant (1.28.0)
      active_utils (>= 1.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.11)
      builder (>= 2.0.0)
      i18n
      json (>= 1.5.1)
      money
      nokogiri
    activemodel (3.2.9)
      activesupport (= 3.2.9)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.9)
      activemodel (= 3.2.9)
      activesupport (= 3.2.9)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.9)
      activemodel (= 3.2.9)
      activesupport (= 3.2.9)
    activesupport (3.2.9)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    acts_as_list (0.1.4)
    addressable (2.3.4)
    airbrake (3.1.11)
      activesupport
      builder
      json
    akami (1.2.0)
      gyoku (>= 0.4.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    awesome_nested_set (2.1.4)
      activerecord (>= 3.0.0)
    aws-sdk (1.3.9)
      httparty (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)
      uuidtools (~> 2.1)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    builder (3.0.4)
    cancan (1.6.7)
    capistrano (2.15.2)
      highline
      net-scp (>= 1.0.0)
      net-sftp (>= 2.0.0)
      net-ssh (>= 2.0.14)
      net-ssh-gateway (>= 1.1.0)
    capybara (2.1.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    childprocess (0.3.9)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    choice (0.1.6)
    chronic (0.9.1)
    chunky_png (1.2.8)
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cocaine (0.5.2)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
    colorize (0.6.0)
    columnize (0.3.6)
    compass (0.12.2)
      chunky_png (~> 1.2)
      fssm (>= 0.2.7)
      sass (~> 3.1)
    compass-rails (1.0.3)
      compass (>= 0.12.2, < 0.14)
    crack (0.3.2)
    database_cleaner (0.9.1)
    debugger (1.5.0)
      columnize (>= 0.3.1)
      debugger-linecache (~> 1.2.0)
      debugger-ruby_core_source (~> 1.2.0)
    debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
    debugger-ruby_core_source (1.2.0)
    deface (1.0.0)
      colorize (>= 0.5.8)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails (>= 3.1)
    devise (2.2.3)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (~> 3.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.1)
    devise-encryptable (0.1.1)
      devise (>= 2.1.0.rc)
    devise-i18n (0.8.3)
    diff-lcs (1.2.4)
    ean (0.2.0)
    email_spec (1.4.0)
      launchy (~> 2.1)
      mail (~> 2.2)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.3)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    factory_girl (4.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
      factory_girl (~> 4.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    fattr (2.2.1)
    faye-websocket (0.4.7)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.0)
    ffaker (1.12.1)
    ffi (1.9.0)
    fssm (0.2.10)
    gyoku (1.0.0)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
    haml (4.0.2)
      tilt
    highline (1.6.11)
    hike (1.2.3)
    http_parser.rb (0.5.3)
    httparty (0.8.3)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      multi_xml
    httpi (2.0.2)
      rack
    i18n (0.6.5)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-fileupload-rails (0.4.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    jquery-rails (2.3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.0)
    kaminari (0.13.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    launchy (2.3.0)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    libv8 (3.11.8.17)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.25)
    mini_portile (0.5.1)
    money (5.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.4)
      json
    multi_json (1.8.2)
    multi_xml (0.5.5)
    mysql2 (0.3.11)
    net-scp (1.1.0)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-sftp (2.1.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (2.6.7)
    net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    newrelic_rpm (3.6.7.152)
    nokogiri (1.6.0)
      mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)
    nori (2.1.0)
    options (2.3.0)
      fattr
    orm_adapter (0.4.0)
    paperclip (2.8.0)
      activerecord (>= 2.3.0)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.2)
      cocaine (>= 0.0.2)
      mime-types
    poltergeist (1.2.0)
      capybara (~> 2.1.0)
      faye-websocket (~> 0.4, >= 0.4.4)
      http_parser.rb (~> 0.5.3)
    polyamorous (0.5.0)
      activerecord (~> 3.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    pr_geohash (1.0.0)
    progress_bar (1.0.0)
      highline (~> 1.6.1)
      options (~> 2.3.0)
    rabl (0.7.2)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.14)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    rack (1.4.5)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.9)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.9)
      actionpack (= 3.2.9)
      activerecord (= 3.2.9)
      activeresource (= 3.2.9)
      activesupport (= 3.2.9)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.9)
    rails-erd (1.1.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      choice (~> 0.1.6)
      ruby-graphviz (~> 1.0.4)
    rails-i18n (0.7.3)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
    railties (3.2.9)
      actionpack (= 3.2.9)
      activesupport (= 3.2.9)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (10.1.0)
    ransack (0.7.2)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activerecord (~> 3.0)
      polyamorous (~> 0.5.0)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    ref (1.0.4)
    rsolr (1.0.9)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
    rspec (2.13.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.13.0)
    rspec-core (2.13.1)
    rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
    rspec-rails (2.13.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.13.0)
    ruby-graphviz (1.0.8)
    ruby-prof (0.13.0)
    rubyzip (0.9.9)
    sass (3.2.12)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    savon (2.2.0)
      akami (~> 1.2.0)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      gyoku (~> 1.0.0)
      httpi (~> 2.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.0)
      nori (~> 2.1.0)
      wasabi (~> 3.1.0)
    select2-rails (3.5.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    selenium-webdriver (2.35.1)
      childprocess (>= 0.2.5)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rubyzip (< 1.0.0)
      websocket (~> 1.0.4)
    simple_form (2.1.0)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activemodel (~> 3.0)
    spree_skrill (1.0.2)
      spree_core (>= 1.0.0)
    spree_usa_epay (1.0.2)
      savon
      spree_core (>= 1.0.0)
    sprockets (2.2.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    state_machine (1.1.2)
    steak (2.0.0)
      capybara (>= 1.0.0)
      rspec-rails (>= 2.5.0)
    stringex (1.3.3)
    therubyracer (0.11.4)
      libv8 (~> 3.11.8.12)
      ref
    thor (0.18.1)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    timecop (0.6.1)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tunnels (1.2.2)
      eventmachine
    tzinfo (0.3.38)
    uglifier (2.0.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    useragent (0.6.0)
    uuidtools (2.1.4)
    vcr (2.5.0)
    warden (1.2.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    wasabi (3.1.0)
      httpi (~> 2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.0)
    webmock (1.8.11)
      addressable (>= 2.2.7)
      crack (>= 0.1.7)
    websocket (1.0.7)
    whenever (0.8.2)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.4)
      chronic (>= 0.6.3)
    wicked_pdf (0.9.6)
      rails
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)
    zurb-foundation (4.1.2)
      sass (>= 3.2.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  airbrake
  capistrano
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  compass-rails
  database_cleaner
  debugger (~> 1.5.0)
  devise-encryptable
  devise-i18n
  ean
  email_spec
  factory_girl_rails
  haml
  httparty
  jquery-fileupload-rails
  jquery-rails
  kaminari
  launchy
  mysql2
  newrelic_rpm
  poltergeist
  progress_bar
  rails (= 3.2.9)
  rails-erd
  rails-i18n
  rspec
  ruby-prof
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  selenium-webdriver
  simple_form
  spree!
  spree_auth_devise!
  spree_i18n!
  spree_ipayment!
  spree_paypal_express!
  spree_skrill
  spree_usa_epay
  spree_wirecard!
  steak
  sunspot_rails!
  sunspot_solr!
  therubyracer
  timecop
  tunnels
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
  useragent
  vcr
  webmock (~> 1.8.3)
  whenever
  wicked_pdf
  zurb-foundation
```

Sometimes it throws the error, sometimes it don't, and sometimes it is even caused by some file in the state machine gem. At `line_item_decorator.rb:7` there is only a database query, nothing special.

I'm on Mac OS X 10.8.5, but the error also happens on Ubuntu 13.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: I had this same issue before, it was caused by `nokogiri` (`libxml` to be more precise) I tried every solution I found with no avail. The only thing that fixed the issue for me is to disable GC (`GC.disable`) but that's isn't a real solution. have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160289/upgraded-to-ruby-1-9-2-and-getting-segmentation-fault-errors-in-nokogiri), [here](http://art-of-fine-code.redbubble.com/blog/2012/06/20/nokogiri-goes-bump-or-segfaults-in-the-night-dot-dot-dot/) and [here](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/881)

Comment: and [this](https://github.com/xml4r/libxml-ruby/issues/57)

Comment: Hey if you found the solution please update your post. It would be great if I don't have to disable `GC` to run my test.

Answer (score 7):

Are you developing on Mac? Nokogiri is the gem that causes those segmentation faults; it's a very common issue on Mac, especially if you have brew installed.

You can review the right way to install nokogiri at [this url](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html).

First, uninstall all nokogiri versions from your system:

```
gem uninstall nokogiri
(select all)
```

Next, if you have brew, try to run:

```
brew install libxml2 libxslt
brew link --force libxml2 libxslt
```

and finally install the versions of nokogiri that you need (based on your Gemfile, it's 1.6.0):

```
gem install nokogiri --version 1.6.0 -- --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.1/include/libxml2  \
                                     --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.1/lib  \
                                     --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28 \
                                     --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/include  \
                                     --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/lib
```

Finally, bundle again and you should be able to run the specs without problems.

Comment: I think latest version of `nokogiri` will have `libxml` and `libxslt`  embedded inside the gem to fix dependency problem. Also, AFAIK `libxml` version `2.9.x` is not supported yet. https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri#requirements

For the record, I have tried that but it didn't fix the issue for me.

Comment: I tried that too, and indeed, it has `libxml` and `libxslt` embedded. Unfortunately, your solution didn't fix my error.

Comment: Worked for me but after installing libxml, libxslt and libiconv with brew and `brew link --force` them