# Nokogiri segfault

Tags: ruby, segmentation-fault, nokogiri

For some unknown reason nokogiri(1.6.2) segfault on my macbook.

I've no idea why and what I should provide.

The crash report is too big to be posted on SO so here is a [link to the gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/484633a9cfde1a5574fb)

Comment: possible duplicate of [RSpec throws segmentation fault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491783/rspec-throws-segmentation-fault)

Comment: I tried the solution on that thread but did not work. Also, I'm not using the same version of ruby and nokogiri

Comment: I'll retract my vote then.