# Installed RVM and now my rails server won't start

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, osx-lion, rvm

I had started the Rails app yesterday and got everything working. 
Then today I decided to go with RVM, as I realized I might have need of it. So I uninstalled all gems, installed RVM and have now a working(?) RVM.

I reinstalled the gems and now my `bundle exec rails server` crashes

> $ bundle exec rails server
>
> [BUG] cross-thread violation on rb_gc()
>
> (null)
>
> Abort trap: 6

[Crashreport](http://pastie.org/3098737)

I have no idea whats wrong with my installation, as there is no reasonable error' which I could understand. :(

Edit: [Gemfile](http://pastie.org/3098753)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great, the answer was to use ruby 1.9.3 instead of 1.9.2 ...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding gcc-4.2 as your default C compiler to your bash profile:

```
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

Then reinstall your rubies. You need XCode 4.1 to be installed before 4.2, otherwise you won't have gcc-4.2. The easiest way is to uninstall 4.2, and then install 4.1, then upgrade to 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this solution: [Error: cross-thread violation on rb_gc()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413209/error-cross-thread-violation-on-rb-gc)

It looks like this might be an issue with a ruby version difference between your system and RVM. There are a few other articles out there on how to clean this up, like the one below, but I'm not sure which one will work for you:

http://blog.ubrio.us/nix/osx-rubygems-and-cross-thread-violations-in-rb_gc/

Comment: No luck there. It did list `eventmachine, ffi, gherkin and thin` with that shell command from the blog. But reinstalling them didn't do anything...