# Bundle says gem is missing - but it's not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rbenv

**Background**

I am maintaining the *content* of a Ruby On Rails site, but I really have no experience with Rails.

When trying to run the Rails server: `rails s` I get this:

> Could not find activesupport-3.2.0 in any of the sources
>
> Run `bundle install` to install missing gems

I run bundle install

> Gem::InstallError: factory_girl requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2. An
>   error occured while installing factory_girl (3.2.0), and Bundler
>   cannot continue.
>
> Make sure that `gem install factory_girl -v '3.2.0'`
>   succeeds before bundling.

Okay, I install factory_girl as per the instructions:

> Successfully installed factory_girl-3.2.0
>   1 gem installed

Run bundle install again:

> Gem::InstallError: factory_girl
>   requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2. An error occured while installing
>   factory_girl (3.2.0), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that `gem
>   install factory_girl -v '3.2.0'` succeeds before bundling.

Do you have any idea?

**Info**

Yesterday I got a cross-tread error when trying to run rails server. So as per [this SO advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175872/cross-thread-violation-on-rb-gc) I advice I've nuked RVM and installed rbenv and bundler instead of RVM.

I have tried with both Ruby 1.9.3-p125 and 1.9.3-rc1

Output of `gem list` shows factory_girl as installed.

- ...
- factory_girl (3.2.0)
- ...

Output of `gem environment`shows the problem might has something todo with ruby 1.9.1 being installed also?

> RubyGems Environment:
>     - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.10
>     - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2011-09-23 patchlevel -1) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
>     - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/andreas/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
>     - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/andreas/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-rc1/bin/ruby
>     - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/andreas/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-rc1/bin
>     - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
>       - ruby
>       - x86_64-darwin-11
>     - GEM PATHS:
>        - /Users/andreas/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
>        - /Users/andreas/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
>     - GEM CONFIGURATION:
>        - :update_sources => true
>        - :verbose => true
>        - :benchmark => false
>        - :backtrace => false
>        - :bulk_threshold => 1000
>        - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
>     - REMOTE SOURCES:
>        - http://rubygems.org/

Comment: Which ruby version do you get when entering in terminal: ruby -v

Comment: I think your ruby is 1.9.1.... => /Users/andreas/.gem/ruby/1.9.1

Comment: @RobinH I get: ruby 1.9.3dev (2011-09-23 revision 33323) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]

Comment: @shuriu - I don't think so - see above...

Comment: can I just delete: - /Users/andreas/.gem/ruby/1.9.1?

Comment: Really confused: `ls /Users/andreas/.gem/ruby` outputs a "1.8" dir - no 1.9.1 in sight?

Comment: @jdoe you are referring to the specific projects `Gemfile.lock`? When I remove it and run `bundle check`, I get the same song unsatisfied dependencies. I am asked to do a `bundle install`. Which I do and TADAAA - no problem... Please explain you magic and let me give you some karma.

Comment: @BenMiller Thanks - but it seems the problem was `Gemfile.lock`.

Comment: try not `rails s` but `bundle exec rails s`

Comment: @shuriu That `1.9.1` doesn't really correspond to the version of Ruby - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564210/why-are-we-installing-ruby-1-9-2-1-9-3-gems-into-a-1-9-1-folder

Comment: @jdoe please come and collect karma points by provinding your comment as an aswer. The I will mark it as "accepted". Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jdoe answered in the comments. And it worked. Apparently I needed to delete `Gemfile.lock`.

I don't know why or how though. I am just posting this here, until @jdoe shows up and collects his points with a real answer.

Comment: Deleting the lock file means implicitly updating all the gems to the latest versions, which you might not want to.

Answer (score 3):

Try reinstalling all the gems with the following command:

```sh
bundle install --redownload
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
bundle exec rails s
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first - I have no experience with rbenv.

One of the nice things with RVM is that it helps make fairly explicit what the moving parts of your Ruby environment are.

*rvm list* will give you a list of Rubies
*rvm gemset list* will give you a list of gemsets (this should not be necessary if using bundler)

Now, here are a few tricky things:

- Gemfile is used by Bundler to determine what to install
- If nothing is specified, Bundler will try to install the latest version of a gem
- If the latest version of a gem is not compatible with your current Ruby, then ...

  - You can change version of Ruby (*rvm install 1.9.3* for instance)
  - You can tell the Gemfile to specify which version of the gem you want, with varying degrees of strictness.

    - Can you tell I like indenting bullet points?
    - gem "vcr", "~> 1.11.3" # => this will say you prefer 1.11.3 but anything within 1.11 range is acceptable
    - gem 'factory_girl', '3.2.0' # => this says, only install version 3.2.0 of factory_girl, nothing else

In addition, before anything else, you should run *bundle check* to see what bundler has to say about your gems.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the gems you are installing is in the Gemfile, because if the gem is not added to the Gemfile, even if you installed it manually, your Rails app is not getting it.

Sample Gemfile would be

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.0'

gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3'
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'

#authorization
gem 'authlogic'
gem 'hoptoad_notifier'

#reporting
gem 'lazy_high_charts'

group :test do
  gem 'rspec', '2.0.0'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0 '
  gem "test-unit"
end
```