# ruby 1.9.3p286 and factory_girl_rails error on bundle install in application directory

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

I do have a problem with bundler install for the gem 'factory_girl_rails' and I don't know how to resolve.

Each time I run bundle install in the application/project directory the following error is thrown:
(it doesn't matter if I create a new rails app and add factory_girl to the gemfile either)

> Gem::InstallError: factory_girl requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.

An error occured while installing factory_girl (4.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue.

Make sure that `gem install factory_girl -v '4.1.0'` succeeds before bundling.

When I type 'gem intall factory_girl_rails' in the terminal it successfully installs.

## My configuration:

```
osx mountain lion
ruby 1.9.3p286
gem 1.8.24
rails 3.2.8

which ruby:
/usr/local/bin/ruby

which gem:
/usr/local/bin/gem

which rails:
/usr/local/bin/rails

gem list:
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.8)
actionpack (3.2.8)
activemodel (3.2.8)
activerecord (3.2.8)
activeresource (3.2.8)
activesupport (3.2.8)
addressable (2.3.2)
arel (3.0.2)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
best_in_place (1.1.2)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
builder (3.1.4, 3.0.4)
bundler (1.2.1)
cancan (1.6.8)
capybara (1.1.2)
carrierwave (0.7.0)
childprocess (0.3.6)
client_side_validations (3.2.1)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.4.0, 1.3.3)
country_select (1.0.1)
devise (2.1.2)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
evernote (1.2.1)
evernote-thrift (1.22.1)
execjs (1.4.0)
factory_girl (4.1.0)
factory_girl_rails (4.1.0)
faraday (0.8.4)
ffi (1.1.5)
geocoder (1.1.4)
guard (1.4.0)
guard-rspec (2.1.0)
hashie (1.2.0)
hike (1.2.1)
httpauth (0.2.0)
i18n (0.6.1)
io-console (0.3)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.1.3)
json (1.7.5)
jwt (0.1.5)
libwebsocket (0.1.5)
listen (0.5.3)
mail (2.4.4)
metaclass (0.0.1)
mime-types (1.19)
minitest (4.1.0)
mocha (0.12.7)
multi_json (1.3.7, 1.3.6)
multipart-post (1.1.5)
nested_form (0.2.3)
nifty-generators (0.4.6)
nokogiri (1.5.5)
oauth (0.4.7)
oauth2 (0.8.0)
omniauth (1.1.1)
omniauth-dropbox (0.2.0)
omniauth-evernote (1.2.0)
omniauth-facebook (1.4.1)
omniauth-foursquare (0.0.8)
omniauth-google (1.0.2)
omniauth-google-oauth2 (0.1.13)
omniauth-instagram (1.0.0)
omniauth-linkedin (0.0.8)
omniauth-oauth (1.0.1)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1)
omniauth-salesforce (1.0.3)
omniauth-twitter (0.0.13)
omniauth-windowslive (0.0.8.1)
omniauth-xing (0.1.3)
omniauth-yahoo (0.0.4)
orm_adapter (0.4.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-protection (1.2.0)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.8)
railties (3.2.8)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12)
redis (3.0.2)
rmagick (2.13.1)
rspec (2.11.0)
rspec-core (2.11.1)
rspec-expectations (2.11.3)
rspec-mocks (2.11.3)
rspec-rails (2.11.4)
rubygems-update (1.8.24)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
sass (3.2.2, 3.2.1)
sass-rails (3.2.5)
selenium-webdriver (2.25.0)
simple_form (2.0.4)
sinatra (1.3.3)
sprockets (2.8.0, 2.1.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.6)
thor (0.16.0)
thrift (0.9.0)
thrift_client (0.8.2)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.12, 1.4.11)
tzinfo (0.3.35, 0.3.34, 0.3.33)
uglifier (1.3.0)
warden (1.2.1)
xpath (0.1.4)
```

**Content of the Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'



# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'


group :test, :development do
  gem 'aruba'
  gem 'cucumber'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'mongoid-rspec'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'jasmine'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end


# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'

gem 'devise'
gem 'mongoid'
gem 'mongoid_spacial'
gem 'haml'
gem 'bson_ext'
gem 'rails-backbone'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Gemfile.lock` file, and run `bundle install` again. Or run `bundle update`. Ref: [Bundle says gem is missing - but it's not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413972/bundle-says-gem-is-missing-but-its-not)

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick answer, I'd already deleted the Gemfile.lock as mentioned in the linked article but without success neither bundle install nor bundle update works. I'm still getting the same error. - Info: I'm using homebrew and ruby 1.9.3 is system default

Comment: @NULL thanks for editing I missed / didn't know how to format the gems list correctly - well done ;-)

Comment: Bundle check throws the following error: Your Gemfile's dependencies could not be satisfied - install missing gems

Comment: Please include your `Gemfile` content as well in the question. On a different note, have you tried using either `rvm` or `rbenv` to manage multiple versions of ruby? Using `rvm` along with `gemsets` would make it much easier to manage dependencies within a project.

Comment: Hi, content of the Gemfile inserted above.

Comment: In older installations I've used RVM but now I would like to try with homebrew - has to work as well, right? - Addition: Currently I've only installed Ruby 1.9.3p286

Comment: Cracked it! - I have to "update" bundler.
I issued the following command:

    gem install bundler

The following messages is shown:
Successfully installed bundler-1.2.1

After that I restarted terminal and again issued the "bundle install" command in the application/projects directory.

Now factory_girl and factory_girl_rails installed successfully! :-)

Source: [http://gembundler.com/][1]


  [1]: http://gembundler.com/

Comment: Congrats! About `brew` and `rvm` they are for different purposes; you can use both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Cracked it!

I have to "update" bundler.

I issued the following command: gem install bundler

The following messages is shown: Successfully installed bundler-1.2.1

After that I restarted terminal and again issued the "bundle install" command in the application/projects directory.

Now factory_girl and factory_girl_rails installed successfully! :-)

Source: [gembundler.com](http://gembundler.com)